How to Customize Histogram Bar Edges in Tradovate's Trading Platform from Rounded to Square?
I'm working with a custom indicator in Tradovate's trading platform, specifically adjusting the appearance of histogram bars within a JavaScript (JS) file. My current issue is that the histogram bars, which represent data in a MACD indicator, are displayed with rounded corners, and I need to change them to have square edges for better visual clarity.
I have the JS code for the MACD indicator, which uses a drawLine method from Tradovate's API to plot the histogram. However, this method doesn't seem to provide an option to adjust the corner style of the bars. The API documentation I found only details this drawLine method and doesn't mention any direct way to draw rectangles or adjust line cap styles.
const predef = require("./tools/predef");
const meta = require("./tools/meta");
const SMA = require("./tools/SMA");
const EMA = require('./tools/EMA');
const WMA = require('./tools/WMA');
const MMA = require('./tools/MMA');

const p = require("./tools/plotting");

function HullMovingAverage(period) {
    function hma(value) {
        return hma.push(value);
    }

    hma.reset = () => {
        hma.state = {
            wmaLong: WMA(period),
            wmaShort: WMA(period),
            wmaSqrt: WMA(Math.sqrt(period)),
            avg: 0
        };
    };

    hma.push = (value) => {
        const wmaLong = hma.state.wmaLong(value);
        const wmaShort = hma.state.wmaShort(value) * 2;
        const wmaDiff = wmaShort - wmaLong;
        const wmaSqrt = hma.state.wmaSqrt(wmaDiff);
        return wmaSqrt;
    }

    hma.avg = () => hma.state.wmaSqrt.avg();

    hma.reset();

    return hma;
}

function getMovingAverage(averageType, period) {
    
    let ma;
    switch (averageType) {
        case "hma":
            ma = HullMovingAverage(period);
            break;
        case "sma":
            ma = SMA(period);
            break;
        case "wma":
            ma = WMA(period);
            break;
        case "mma":
            ma = MMA(period);
            break;
        default:
            ma = EMA(period);
    }
    
    return ma;
}

class macdMultiColoredHistogram {
    init() {
        this.signalEMA = getMovingAverage(this.props.averageType, this.props.signal);
        this.fastEMA = getMovingAverage(this.props.averageType, this.props.fast);
        this.slowEMA = getMovingAverage(this.props.averageType, this.props.slow);
    }

    map(entity, index, inputSeries) {
        
        let difference;
        let macd;
        let signal;
        
        if (index >= this.props.slow - 1) {

            const value = entity.value();
            macd = this.fastEMA(value) - this.slowEMA(value);
            signal = this.signalEMA(macd);
            difference = macd - signal;
        }
        
        return {
            macd,
            signal,
            difference,
            zero: 0,
        };
    }

    filter(d) {
        return predef.filters.isNumber(d.macd);
    }
}

function histogramPlotter(canvas, indicatorInstance, history) {
    
    if (!indicatorInstance.props.showHistogram) {
        return;
    }
    
    
    let item1;

    for(let i=0; i<history.data.length; ++i) {
        const item = history.get(i);

        if (item1 && i > 0 && item.difference !== undefined) {
            
            
            const difference = item.difference;
            const diffLast = item1.difference;
            let histColor = indicatorInstance.props.posRisingColor;

            if (difference > 0) {
                
                if (difference > diffLast) {
                    histColor = indicatorInstance.props.posRisingColor;
                } else {
                    histColor = indicatorInstance.props.posFallingColor;
                }
            } else {
                if (difference < diffLast) {
                    histColor = indicatorInstance.props.negFallingColor;
                } else {
                    histColor = indicatorInstance.props.negRisingColor;
                }
            }
            
            const x = p.x.get(item);

            canvas.drawLine(
                p.offset(x, item.difference),
                p.offset(x, 0),
                {
                    color: histColor,
                    relativeWidth: 0.90,
                    opacity: 0.75,
                });
        }

        item1 = item;
    }
}


module.exports = {
    name: "MACD",
    description: "YAZDANI - MACD",
    calculator: macdMultiColoredHistogram,
    areaChoice: meta.AreaChoice.NEW,
    tags: ["Otto.Blink"],
    params: {
        fast: predef.paramSpecs.period(22),
        slow: predef.paramSpecs.period(36),
        signal: predef.paramSpecs.period(19),
        averageType: predef.paramSpecs.enum({
            sma: 'Simple',
            ema: 'Exponential',
            wma: 'Weighted',
            // mma: 'Modified',
            hma: 'Hull',
        }, 'ema'),
        dividerForHistogram: predef.paramSpecs.enum({
            spacer: '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
        }, 'spacer'),
        showHistogram: predef.paramSpecs.bool(true),
        posRisingColor: predef.paramSpecs.color("#1BAD8D"),
        posFallingColor: predef.paramSpecs.color("#9BEBD8"),
        negRisingColor: predef.paramSpecs.color("#EE939E"),
        negFallingColor: predef.paramSpecs.color("#E01515"),
    },
    validate(obj) {
        if (obj.slow < obj.fast) {
            return meta.error("slow", "Slow period should be larger than fast period");
        }
    },
    inputType: meta.InputType.ANY,
    plotter: [
        { type: 'multiline', field: ['macd', 'signal', 'zero', 'difference'] },
        predef.plotters.custom(histogramPlotter),
    ],
    plots: {
        macd: { title: "MACD" },
        signal: { title: "Signal" },
        zero: { title: "Zero", displayOnly: true },
        difference: {title: "Difference"}
    },
    schemeStyles: {
        dark: {
            zero: predef.styles.plot({ color: "white", lineStyle: 1, lineWidth: 1, opacity: 100 }),
            macd: predef.styles.plot("#3180DD"),
            signal: predef.styles.plot("#eee140"),
        }
    },
};


I tried adjusting properties such as relativeWidth, width, and opacity in hopes of simulating square-edged bars by making the lines thicker and reducing gaps between them, but this approach hasn't given me the sharp, square edges I'm looking for.
           canvas.drawLine(
                p.offset(x, item.difference),
                p.offset(x, 0),
                {
                    color: histColor,
                    relativeWidth: 0.90,
                    opacity: 0.75,
                });


I was hoping that by manipulating these properties, I could visually create the appearance of square edges on the histogram bars. Ideally, there would be a way to directly draw bars with square edges or adjust the line cap style from rounded to square.
